# Чтение данных из Socket без задержки

Tags: java, android, сокет

Имеется приложение, логика которого следующая: 1) Приложение подключается к серверу. 2) При нажатии на кнопку приложение читает данные от сервера.
Проблема в том, что приложение при нажатии на кнопку чтения данных приостанавливается на неопределенное время.
К примеру сервер отвечает строкой: `{whats,need}`
Приложение читает ответ, но выполнение продолжается только тогда, когда приходит следующее сообщение, либо происходит отключение.
Код чтения:

```
public String read() throws Exception{
        String message = "";
        if (inputStream.available()>0) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            inputStream.read(buffer,0,inputStream.available());
            message = new String(buffer);
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Инициализация inputStream:

```
InputStream inputStream;
inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
```

Как избавиться от этой болячки?

Comment: а кто этот сервер делал?  у вас есть доступ к нему код посмотреть?

Comment: весёленький похоже сервер... "Whats need" (если не догадываете) означает "Те чо нада?" )))

Comment: Сервер мой. Работает больше года (служит для раздачи некоторой инфы). Использую другими проектами (С другими проектами (не на java) все работает здорово). Сервер использует стороннюю библиотеку для работы с сетью.

Comment: я чесскажу не делал из джавы никогда такого (вообще признаюсь никогда ничего на джаве не делал). Но имхо если через JS например с этим конкретным сокетом нет проблем, такой же сценарий работает, то на стороне джавы что-то не так - извините, не помогу ничем тут...

Answer (score 3):

Объясняю: запускать что-то тяжелое в главном потоке приложения (он же *UI* поток) — нельзя. В тяжелые задачи можно отнести: чтение из БД, чтение из сервера, любая работа с файлами и длительные расчеты.

Для выполнения кода в других потоках есть такие варианты решения проблемы:

1. [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) — уже устаревшая (в плане подхода разработки) вещь, но, решая специфическую задачу для себя, может подойти. Хотя он все равно не так удобен, как, например `Loader`.
2. [Intent Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) — обычный `Service`, но предназначенный для выполнения тяжелых задач в фоне. Вполне неплохая вещь, если Вы не хотите получать результат обратно в приложение (как, например, при чтении из БД — нужно получить результат в виде массива для отображения в приложении), а просто выполнить задачу и забыть (скачай файл в телефон и просто сказать пользователю "Готово!").
3. [Loader](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html?hl=ru) — одна из основных вещей для выполнения длительных задач с удобным механизмом получения ответа в вызывавшую часть приложения. Устойчива к пересозданиям `Activity` и, что тоже интересно, не захватывает контекст, хоть и использует его.
4. [RxJava](http://reactivex.io/) со своими методами `subscribeOn` и `observeOn` — вызывается просто, в связке с лямбдами от [Retrolambda](http://reactivex.io/) выглядит красиво. Всего в пару строк указываете в каком потоке и что выполнять. Но, опять же, нужно быть осторожно, чтобы не захватить контекст лямбдой (из-за особенностей работы *Retrolambda*).
5. [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) — старый добрый "тред". Не устойчив к перезапускам активностей, имеет другие проблемы во время написания, но, как и `AsyncTask`, если нужно написать быстро и для себя (исключительно для себя) — подходит (в реальном приложении использовать строго запрещаю, но для себя и для имитации работы — незаменимая вещь).

Если правильно и надежно — нужно использовать `Loader` или `RxJava`. Если быстро, но ненадёжно и из палок с т.п. вещами — `Thread` + запрет смены ориентации устройства.

Comment: Такую кашу написали, что даже конструктивно ответить тяжело. В каждом пункте прослеживается линия непонимания каждого инструмента. Async был изменен и сейчас вполне устойчив, как вы пишите для отслеживания состояния компонентов и ошибок, retrolambda на данный момент намного увереннее себя чувствует чем нативный способ от google, во время индексации лямбда, Loader много разных, не все они подходят ддя, да и некоторые являются частью того же AsyncTask, в коробке всеравно те же Thread, IntentService далеко не Service , хоть и форкается от него, вообщемм аккуратнее в таких ответах.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei +

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, даже не знал, что `AsyncTask`'ом еще занимаются, поправил в ответе. Однако, к плане использования он все же не сильно удобен (для меня, как минимум). Я не сравнивал `Retrolambda` ни с чем (да и, если честно, про нативный способ от google), но она имеет свойство вызывать утечки памяти из-за переданного внутрь контекста (если я не ошибаюсь, она создает анонимный класс, который, само собой, хранит ссылку). `Loader`'ы разные, поэтому я говорил обобщенно, чтобы человек выбрал сам. `IntentService` в плане реализации другой, но суть одинакова (опять же, для меня).

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, да и говорить о том, что в "коробке" все состоит из базовых вещей, таких как `Thread` даже говорить не стоит, это должно быть очевидно. Это то же самое сказать, что в основе всего единицы и нули :). Если я ошибся в предыдущем комментарии — поправьте меня, все-таки я не гуру (как минимум, пока что :D), мне еще многое предстоит узнать.

Comment: @Rostislav Dugin суть в том, что программа в любом случае должна ждать отработки чтения с сервера. Вопрос в другом - почему я получаю данные только тогда, когда сервер присылает что то еще после, либо рвет соединение.